# Can flow chart be a use case model?

Tags: uml, use-case

Could you please let me know whether flow chart can be consider for use case modelling? As far as I know it just represents a flow of events and do not have any actors, so cannot be considered for modelling.

Can some some experts confirm this?

Answer (score 3):

Flow charts are the ancestors of activity diagrams and as such very rudimentary. You can use flow charts along with use case modeling, but it is not a good idea. First you will limit yourself in the language (think of a native speaker vs. a foreigner that knows only a little vocabulary). Second is that activity diagrams are matured to a standard within UML. So you can expect more people to be able to read and understand them correctly. And last: activity diagrams are the basis for BPMN which is going to be the next step after use cases (it brings a whole set of new standardized language elements which allows expression of what is in and behind a use case).

And yes, your basic assumption is correct: no relation to actors. So you'd need to find ways to express that outside the flow chart.

See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart).